# Make a portion of div transparent with HTML5 and canvas

Tags: html, canvas, transparency, html5-canvas, mask

I'm working on scratch off HTML5 effect and I need both background and foreground to be DIVs with animated content inside. So I need Foreground DIV on top of Background DIV and I want to mask regions of the Foreground DIV as user scratches them off. Is it possible?

I need to create this: http://beej.us/x/scratcher/, but with DIVs instead of both background and foreground images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a portion of a div transparent using a canvas.

you can sorta *pretend*, like if the background of the div is white you can paint white over parts of the div. So you sorta make the illusion of it like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4zL/1/). But that's really situational.